# How to get string in between forth and fifth slash(/) in oracle without using regular expressions

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have a string like below

```
/doc/Alldocs/attachment/2345455/122222/0/C/0%20%XYZ%ABC%20K
```

I need to get the string in between the forth and fifth slash that means `2345455`

Currently I am using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to get the result.

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR('/doc/Alldocs/attachment/2345455/122222/0/C/0%20%XYZ%ABC%20K', '[^/ ]+', 1, 4)
```

But this is really impacting the performance, in my database it is taking long time to return the result.

Is there any other way we can get this information faster ?  something like `split, Instr` etc ??

I am newbie to oracle could you please help me to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the old `SUBSTR` + `INSTR` combination, as usual.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '/doc/Alldocs/attachment/2345455/122222/0/C/0%20%XYZ%ABC%20K' from dual)
  3  select substr(col, instr(col, '/', 1, 4) + 1,
  4                     instr(col, '/', 1, 5) - instr(col, '/', 1, 4) - 1
  5               ) result
  6  from test;

RESULT
-------
2345455

SQL>
```

- the first `INSTR` searches for the 4th slash
- the second `INSTR` searches 5th slash position and subtracts position of the 4th slash - the result is the length of the string to be retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

here is a quick solution with `substr` and `ìnstr`

- first you can get a string `/doc/Alldocs/attachment/2345455`

  ```
  substr(str, 1, length(substr(str,1,instr(str,'/',1,5)))-1)
  ```
- than you can first part of a string

  ```
  with tab as(
    select '/doc/Alldocs/attachment/2345455/122222/0/C/0%20%XYZ%ABC%20K' as str from dual
  )
  select  substr(
             substr(str, 1, length(substr(str,1,instr(str,'/',1,5)))-1)
         ,instr(str,'/',1,4)+1)
    from tab
  ```